# SQL Queries execution

Tags: mysql, tabs

I have a home page with about 20 SQL queries like this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT i.image_id, i.cat_id, i.user_id, i.image_name, i.image_date, i.image_active, i.image_media_file, i.image_thumb_file, i.image_download_url, i.date_last_edited, i.image_model_type, i.image_class, i.image_motor_type".$additional_sql.", c.cat_name".get_user_table_field(", u.", "user_name")."
        FROM (".IMAGES_TABLE." i,  ".CATEGORIES_TABLE." c)
        LEFT JOIN ".USERS_TABLE." u ON (".get_user_table_field("u.", "user_id")." = i.user_id)
        WHERE i.image_active = 1 AND c.cat_id = i.cat_id AND i.cat_id = 71
        ORDER BY i.date_last_edited DESC
        LIMIT 25";
// end new
$result = $site_db->query($sql);
$num_rows = $site_db->get_numrows($result);

if (!$num_rows)  {
  $random_images = "<div><div><div>";
//  $random_images .= $lang['no_new_images'];
  $random_images .= "</div></div></div>";
}
else  {
  $random_images = "<div>";
  $count = 0;
  $bgcounter = 0;
  while ($image_row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)){
    if ($count == 0) {
      $row_bg_number = ($bgcounter++ % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;
      $random_images .= "<div>\n";
    }
    $random_images .= "<div>\n";

    show_image($image_row);
    $random_images .= $site_template->parse_template("home_contents_latest_table");
    $random_images .= "\n</div>\n";
    $count++;
    if ($count == 1) {
      $random_images .= "</div>\n";
      $count = 0;
    }
  } // end while

  if ($count > 0)  {
    $leftover = (1 - $count);
    if ($leftover >= 1) {
      for ($f = 0; $f < $leftover; $f++) {
        $random_images .= "<div>\n&nbsp;\n</div>\n";
      }
      $random_images .= "</div>\n";
    }
  }
  $random_images .= "</div>\n";
} // end else


$site_template->register_vars("home_contents_latest_table", $random_images);
unset($random_images);
```

In the layout of the home page they are grouped in bootstrap tabs so only 4 are visible when the page loads.

My question is. Is it possible to call the queries that are on the non active tabs only when the user clicks on the tab to view its contents?

I know this is a very general question but I would be happy with an answer like, you have to use this or that language to do this or that. I would then investigate by myself...

Thank you very much for any tip.

Fred

Comment: You can use AJAX to load a section only when it is needed.  So you only need to render the section you want with the name of the tab you are looking for then render only that.  So you click on the tab, you send an AJAX call to get the data for that tab.  To be more clear, you use javascript on the client side to request the content you want and respond through php or whatever other language you want.

Comment: By the way you can use something like the jQuery `$.load` function to do the hard work of requesting and placing the data from a page into an HTML Element. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I like the jQuery option since I already have jQuery loaded on the page. Thanks for the help.